# How do I add a QToolButton to a QToolBar in design mode in Qt Creator?

Tags: qt, qt-creator

Design mode on a form of a MainWindow (derived from QMainWindow) does not allow one (in any way I can see) to add a tool button to a tool bar that has been added to the main window.

If I try drag and drop from the widgets panel, I get a "Not allowed" symbol (on Linux, behavior similar on Mac) - I can't drop the tool button on to the tool bar (I took a screenshot, but it is not informative because the "Not allowed" cursor symbol is not shown in the screenshot).

If I right-click on the tool bar, the context menu that pops up has options to append a separator, promote the QToolBar, or remove the tool bar.  No option to add a tool button.  [image: context menu shown in this image]

I have a pretty good idea of how I could add a QToolButton programmatically (unless I misunderstand how QToolBar is supposed to work), but I would prefer that I understand how to use design mode properly.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: You can add actions to the toolbar. If the actions have assigned icons, they become tool buttons. If not, a text is displayed instead.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For adding one tool button to toolBar you should :

1. Create **one Action** like this (Go to **Action Editor** Tab and select **New** Button) :

[image]

2. This Action is your tool button so Create Name and Icon and ...

[image]

3. **Drag that Action and then Drop it in ToolBar like this**

[image]